# How can I reference the TextInput of an editable ComboBox?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, combobox, editor, textinput

I have an editable ComboBox component and I want to reference the TextInput that is shown, in order to programmatically select the Text in it. This is very straightforward on a TextInput:

```
private function selectNameText():void
{
    nameTextInput.selectionBeginIndex = 0;

    nameTextInput.selectionEndIndex = nameTextInput.text.length;
}
```

But I can't find any way to access the TextInput of an editable ComboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that referencing the TextInput for *THIS* reason is unnecessary, since the text is selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when using a ComboBox as a DataGrid itemRenderer.  If you need to reference the TextInput you can override ComboBox and create a getter that returns the protected textInput.  In my case I needed to prevent the auto-selection that occurs when a ComboBox is editable.  Looking at ComboBox, this occurs during updateDisplayList so this should do the trick:

```
package com.whatever.controls
{

import mx.controls.ComboBox;

public class EditableComboBox extends ComboBox
{

    public function EditableComboBox()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        if (editable)
        {
            textInput.selectionBeginIndex   = text.length;
            textInput.selectionEndIndex     = text.length;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

During the Combobox's "Creation Complete" event, you could get the component directly:

```
private function creationCompleteEvt ( evt:FlexEvent ) : void
{
    var targTextInput:UITextInput = UITextInput( myComboBox.getChildAt(2) );
    targTextInput.setSelection( 0, targTextInput.selectionEndIndex );
}
```